# Problemas al instalar PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, windows10, instalacion

alguien me podría ayudar con este problema que estoy teniendo al querer instalar PostgreSQL en Windows 10.
Me sale ese error y no pude encontrar como solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás te sirva leer esto: https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/windows-10-no-se-efectu%C3%B3-ninguna/cf7c6f5e-92ac-40cf-a4a6-0e92559c870b  ¿Tienes alguna versión anterior instalada? ¿Cambiaste las credenciales de usuario?

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta, estuve leyendo ese post, pero la solución no seria la mas optima de tener que crear otro usuario para poder instalarlo que de hecho me función, pero tengo todos los programas y configuraciones en el otro usuario por lo que no seria una solución. Seguiré buscando ver si encuentro alguna otra info